# Make all commits go through lead developer

Tags: github

Is it possible for teams on GitHub to have a lead developer that has to confirm / check every commit to the repository before it gets committed? If yes, how would that be implemented?

Comment: Isn't that what a pull request is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub provides branch protection options which allow you to require certain types of reviewers.  You can protect your main branch, require pull requests to merge code, and require an approving review from someone in the `CODEOWNERS` file.

You can then specify the lead developer individually or a team as the owner for any particular pattern of code in the `CODEOWNERS` file.  Once you've done that, all code must be reviewed by that person or team to be merged.

As a recommendation, it may end up being more practical to add a team even if you have one person in it, since people like to take vacations (or, sometimes, get sick), and it might be convenient to allow someone to easily take over while the lead developer is out by adding a second person.